# ueye.h no such file or directory

Tags: ueye-cam

Working with the UEye Cameras.

I have installed IDS software suit from their website. Version 4.95.2 Using debain package.

I am trying to build ueye_cam ros package. Version 1.0.17 from https://github.com/anqixu/ueye_cam
But the catkin_make fails at ueye.h file, no such file or directory.
I have checked the /opt/ids/ueye/include the file is there. I wonder may be IDS installation is the problem.[image]

Comment: Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)...